# Full Calendar v5 Add Attribute to Event

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

In previous versions of Full Calendar, I would use eventRender to manipulate the event element and add data attributes.

Now that we are tasked with upgrading to v5, it looks like eventRender was deprecated and I cannot find a way to do the same thing.

In the docs here... https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks I am able to use eventDidMount to access the element (el) - however any call to attr or data result in a "attr is not defined" error.

```
 eventDidMount: function(data) {
        data.el.data('res', 123);
    },
```

> data.el.data is not a function

So knowing data is jQuery, I try this...

```
eventDidMount: function(data) {
        $(data.el).data('res', 123);
    },
```

No errors anymore, but also no data attribute added.

So I also tried using "append" to insert an element with an attribute on it, but that adds it as plain text.

```
eventDidMount: function(data) {
    data.el.append('<span data-id="123"></span>');
},
```

Driving myself mad here trying to do something relatively simple, has anyone else run into this?

Comment: _“So knowing data is jQuery, I try […] No errors anymore, but also no data attribute added.”_ - that’s not what `.data()` does, see [docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/): _“Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.”_

Comment: Thank you, I think you are correct - so it was working, I just wasn't seeing it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its always the way. I tear my hair out for 30 mins, post a question, then find an answer.

```
eventDidMount: function(data) {
        data.el.setAttribute("data-id", 123);
    },
```