# React FullCalendar Making like School Timetable Scheduler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm developing an app for my school, like a scheduler but for timtable for teachers. I want something like this:
[image]

I'm using React for my app and [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react) component. I have this component configured like this:

```
<FullCalendar
              weekends={false}
              editable
              droppable
              selectable
              events={events}
              ref={calendarRef}
              rerenderDelay={10}
              initialDate={date}
              initialView={view}
              dayMaxEventRows={30}
              eventDisplay="block"
              headerToolbar={false}
              allDayMaintainDuration
              eventResizableFromStart
              select={handleSelectRange}
              eventDrop={handleDropEvent}
              eventClick={handleSelectEvent}
              eventResize={handleResizeEvent}
              height={isDesktop ? 720 : 'auto'}
              plugins={[listPlugin, dayGridPlugin, timelinePlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
              slotMinTime="8:00:00"
              slotMaxTime="19:00:00"
              displayEventTime={false}
            />
```

But I don't know if I can remove hours first columns and make every event as a separated component with an arrow for expand. I need to write on every event some text (sometimes is a long text), and every week have its own text. All data saved to mongo database, ofcourse.
For now my component looks like this:

[image]

You know if there are any method or propierty for make events stacked without time duration, and fit to content title and then expand it?
I'm not fixed on FullCalendar Component, I can use some other component if it do what I need, but I need to save every week separated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can use the "DayGrid" view in fullCalendar.

It's mentioned [here in the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/daygrid-view) and there's a live demo available there too to show you what it looks like.

With another minor tweak to the `eventDisplay` setting it starts to look similar to your screenshot.

Something like this:

```
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { 
    initialView: "dayGridWeek",
    eventDisplay: "block",
    headerToolbar: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "dayGridWeek,timeGridWeek"
    },
```

...etc. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/KKRqaJe

Of course if you wish you can then add your own further customisations to change the appearance of the events using fullCalendar's [event render hooks](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-render-hooks).

P.S. I'm not a React user so my demo uses vanilla JS but you can get exactly the same result via React syntax.

Comment: It's perfect, I don't see this View and I can do what I want. There are any guide for `event render hook`? So, I really don't know how it work. I need to do something like a collapsable event with expand arrow for description. It's possible?

Comment: I don't know any other comprehensive guide for event render hooks. There is a simple usage example of the callback here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64571398/5947043 . Basically it allows you to modify the HTML of each event almost any way you like in theory.